# Is performing computations inside cellForRowAtIndexPath heavy?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

If I have an NSArray of model objects which I display inside of cell.
Is it a better practice to pre-calculate data and keep it as a property in the model ?

I see a lot of people doing it. So I follow it as well. But is it always required to specific to certain situations ?

In my current screen, we were to generate a string from date property per model for which we were using NSCalendar and NSDateComponents which possibly could have been heavy every-time we call cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Sure it is heavy every time to calculate it in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: the best way to know precise costs of your program is to use instruments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Date formatting is generally regarded as a costly procedure ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) read: Cache Formatters for Efficiency). For these kinds of objects, initializing and caching a single instance is far superior to creating a new one in every call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. This applies to NSCalenders and NSDateformatters and the like. As long as you are only creating a single instance of your date formatting objects, then using them in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should not be a noticeable hit in performance. Try caching these objects in a class method on your cell or your tableview's delegate like so:

```
+ (NSDateFormatter *)dateFormatter {

    static NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = nil;

    if(!dateFormatter) {
        dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE LLL d, yyyy | h:mma"];
    }
    return dateFormatter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called each time a cell is shown or changed (by scrolling), so the source executed here should not be too much, but it depends on your data. If you have to carry a big number of data and prepare all data before the loading time will increase and your device runs out of memory.

Answer (score 1):

The doc for this method states, that you typically re-use the cell for performance reasons. So you can assume, that it is called over and over.

Answer (score 1):

That methods is called everytime a cell is displayed, so I would remove any long calculation from there.

Much depends on your model.

If you are using CoreData, it is a good choice to think about some transient property holding calculated data specifically for Table Cell. NSManagedObject has awakeFromFecth were you can precalculate things. In addition, there's more like fetched controller and the rest.

If you are not using CoreData, I would try to implement the same mechanism, or the significant part of it, but I read that you already doing it. You could do the calculation asynchronously, within an NSOperation, showing a UIActivityIndicator and then populate table as soon as it finished.

Comment: The operation is constant in time. just creating a string for dates so that it can be searchable.

Comment: In this case, I would definitevely do the calculation before, maybe at object creation time, if you have all the data available. If you run xcode profiler, as other suggested, you will see "dirty memory" increase and taking space. Dirty memory is something to avoid  when possible, there's a good video on WWDC explaining that.